# error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths, two sum

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve [this problem from LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/):
Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
You can return the answer in any order.

I wrote the solution (actually I just rewrote my Python solution in C++):

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int m;
        std::vector<int> output;
        std::unordered_map<int, int> d;
        for (int i=0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            m = target - nums[i];
            if (d.count(m)) {
                output = {d[m], i};
                return output;
            } else {
                d[nums[i]] = i;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I get the error:

```
Line 16: Char 5: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
1 error generated.
```

It points on the line before last one.

Comment: @user438383 but the solution is guaranteed so it should run what's in `if` part (including return). If `else` is triggered, it should simply move to the next `i`

Comment: It does not return anything if it reaches to end of for loop.

Comment: @pascalamin the compiler doesnt know thats the case.  You can place a throw at the end of the function or put an assert(false) followed by 'return nums'

Comment: @Kao but the solution is guaranteed to exist, so it should never reach the end of the loop

Comment: The problem is what if there is no ```i``` s to move to. (If it reaches end of loop).

Comment: Thanks you all, I understand now. I added `return output;` at the end of the function and it solved the problem

Comment: Just be careful that you return only when it reached the end of the vector in that ```else``` part

Comment: @Kao it's guaranteed to be not empty

Comment: @SaulMartinez yes, the solution was accepted as correct by the system

Comment: *"You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution"* But compilers don't. For empty vector, you don't return for example.

Comment: If you know a warning is a false positive, you're free to ignore or suppress it. Doing either of those things is always at your own peril though. In a case like this, it would make sense to either make a total function (that is, one that handles all inputs in some way) or to be explicit that the function is partial (e.g., with an explicit precondition coded or at least documented). Either of those establishes to future code readers or maintainers that you've thought this through and made a decision, and it's a good habit if nothing else.